# Java error : unexpected type error

Tags: java

```
  Object[] data=getSelectedRowData(i);
            updateStock((String)data[0], int data[4]);//error line <<
```

says :

> unexpectd type
>   required: value
>  '.class' expected
>  not a
>   statement
>  ';' expected

Here is the full code:

```
  private void saveOrderDiscription() throws SQLException
{
    int rows=rdrtbl.getRowCount();
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        Object[] data=getSelectedRowData(i);
        updateStock((String)data[0], int data[4]);//error line
        String query="INSERT INTO orderdiscription VALUES('"+
          codeFld.getText()+"', '"+data[0]+"', "+data[5]+")";
    dbs.action(query);
    }     
}
```

What can I do ???

Comment: If you use with any IDE , you will see compile time error on your Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `int`

```
Object[] data=getSelectedRowData(i);
            updateStock((String)data[0],  data[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to cast the object to an int then it must be in brackets:

```
Object[] data=getSelectedRowData(i); 
updateStock((String)data[0], (int) data[4]);
```